# QML/Python Getting a list of elements for ComboBox dropdown menu

Tags: python, pyqt5, qml

I'm using pyqt5 and want to get a list of element that will appear on the combobox dropdown menu, I'm trying to instantiate the "model" property of the ComboBox but nothing seems to happen and the method does not seem to work.
Should I use a different decorator than @pyqtSlot? or this a different matter?

my code:

qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

import "../components"

Window {

    id: window
    visible: true
    height: 200
    width: 400
    title: "test"

    ManualSelector { id: customText }


    Rectangle {
        color: '#041645'
        id: mainArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        ColumnLayout {
            anchors.fill: parent

            ComboBox {
                id: cBox
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter
                model: instance.getList() 

                textRole: "display"
               
               

            }
           
            RowLayout{
                    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter


                PressButton {
                    id: pressButtonTwo

                    width: 150
                    height: 50
                    text: "Quit"
                    onClicked: window.close()

                }
                PressButton {
                    id: pressButtonOne
                    width: 150
                    height: 50

                    text: "Submit"
                    onClicked:{
                        window.close()
                    }

                }

  
            }
        }

    }
}
```

python code:

```
python:

    self.set_qml_context_property("instance", self.instance())
    
    @pyqtSlot(name="getList")
        def get_names(self):
            
            names_for_dropdown = ['1', '2', '3']
    
            return names_for_dropdown
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix the problem with changing to the following:

```
@pyqtSlot(result=QVariant, name="getList")
```

and: `return QVariant(names_for_dropdown)`
also remove
`textRole: "display"` from combobox